# MinGW или Cygwin?

Tags: c++, linux, c, mingw, cygwin

Раньше просто компилировал с помощью `g++` на Ubuntu, вытягивая компилятор с помощью пакетного менеджера:

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++
$ g++ -o main.a main.cpp
```

Или на Windows с помощью различных IDE, внутри которых, как мне говорили, стоит MinGW.

Сейчас хочется просто, используя внутреннюю консоль в Окнах, компилировать нативно под них самих же. Почитал про Cygwin и про MinGW, понял, тащемта, что к чему, но остались пробелы - не совсем ясно что мне нужно.

Можно ли подробно, а лучше очень просто, узнать о каждой возможности скомпилировать под Окна?

Comment: А чем вам не подходит Visual Studio?

Comment: @VladD мне все подходит. Я спрашиваю про все доступные возможности компиляции. Хочу найти лучший для меня. И просто к слову, MVS для меня смотрится для проектирования только больших проектов, а сейчас я ничего громадного не пишу.

Comment: Ну вроде там можно и с комстроки компилировать без особых проблем, но я не пробовал, если честно.

Comment: Прекрасно запускаются из ком.строки окон и `g++` и `gcc`. С теми же опциями. Стоит MinGW + Qt. `D:\Qt\testfile>g++ -o main.exe main.cpp`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cygwin - это попытка перенести UNIX окружение в Windows, а MinGW (или современный вариант [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/)) **сосредоточен только на компиляторе GCC**.

Далее, при компиляции программы с помощью Cygwin, по условиям его лицензии вы будете линковаться с его динамической библиотекой `cygwin1.dll` и таскать её всюду за собой, в то время, как с MinGW, вы будете зависеть только от стандартных MSVC библиотек (по-умолчанию от `msvcrt.dll`).

Поскольку MinGW это только компилятор, то есть отдельный проект - [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) который поставляет облегчённую/минимальную версию UNIX окружения в достаточном объёме, чтобы вести разработку почти как в UNIX (там есть `bash`, `git`, `curl` и т.д.). Причём, утилиты для MSYS2 собираются при помощи MinGW.

Про отличия MinGW от Cygwin можно ещё почитать:

- в wiki: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW
- в английской версии SO: [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw)
- ну, и загуглить: [Cygwin vs. MinGW](http://technosaratov.ru/post/view/98)

Comment: А MSYS2 в хранящейся версии компилятора поддерживает новейший стандарт? А вообще, пользуется ли кто-нибудь такими решениями на практике, или все используют модифицированные(свои) версии компиляторов, под разными ИДЕ?

Comment: В MinGW-w64 идёт gcc 5.2, а в простом MinGW - 4.8, если не ошибаюсь. В составе IDE может идти та или иная версия. Чтобы узнать версию компилятора достаточно выполнить команду `gcc -v`. А то, какие фичи поддерживает конкретная версия gcc, можно почитать в справке.

Comment: @ДмитрийThr. Я собираю кросплатформиные проекты используя MSYS2 в window и стандартные утилиты в Linux. Меня устраивает.

Answer (score 2):

Почти всегда лучше брать MinGW.

В Cygwin добавлена прослойка, эмулирующая фичи POSIX (своя костыльная реализация `fork()`; все пути к файлам ваша программа будет воспринимать в Linux-стиле, и т.п.).

Cygwin хорош только в одном случае - когда есть чужая программа, работающая только под Linux, и хочется минимальной кровью портировать ее на винду, не меняя код.

Свои новые программы лучше сразу писать кроссплатформенно, чтобы они могли работать на винде напрямую.

---

Где брать MinGW? Удобнее всего в [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). Там же можно скачать популярные библиотеки в виде пакетов.

Что интересно, в комплект входит форк Cygwin, через который они скомпилировали `bash`, `grep`, и прочие линуксовые утилиты, поэтому всякие мейкфайлы и autotools работают из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

cygwin предоставляет POSIX интерфейс

- как на уровне системных вызовов
- так и на уровне утилит командной строки

MSYS2 предоставляет POSIX интерфейс

- только на уровне утилит командной строки

Comment: Кстати помимо живого проекта MSYS2 есть другой, умирающий проект MSYS.